# Set formula to a range of cells

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

this is simple demo of what i want to do. I want to set a formula to a range of cells(eg. C1 to C10).

```
Range("C1").Formula = "=A1+B1"
```

but how to make formula use dynamic cells like this:

```
Range("C1:C10").Formula = "=Ax+Bx"
```

so in reality it is like,

```
C1 = A1 + B1
C2 = A2 + B2
C3 = A3 + B3
C4 = A4 + B4
C5 = A5 + B5
...
C10 = A10 + B10
```

how to change RHS of this formula to make above working: `Range("C1:C10").Formula = "=Ax+Bx"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would update the formula in C1.  Then copy the formula from C1 and paste it till C10...

Not sure about a more elegant solution

```
Range("C1").Formula = "=A1+B1"
Range("C1").Copy
Range("C1:C10").Pastespecial(XlPasteall)
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this way of doing it except that it's much slower then for example the code from my answer. It's using copy and paste technique which is not efficient when working with many cells.

Comment: @mehow Agreed..  And this would be more understandable and easy to write if the formula is nested and complex.

Comment: prefer neilxdims simpler solution

Answer (score 71):

```
Range("C1:C10").Formula = "=A1+B1"
```

Simple as that.

It autofills (FillDown) the range with the formula.

Comment: This really should be accepted as The Answer, because it accomplishes the O.P.'s request in one line of code.

Comment: Except it is 2 years too late. As is my comment.

Answer (score 11):

I think this is the simplest answer possible: 2 lines and very comprehensible. It emulates the functionality of dragging a formula written in a cell across a range of cells.

```
Range("C1").Formula = "=A1+B1"
Range("C1:C10").FillDown
```

Answer (score 10):

Use FormulaR1C1:

```
Cells((1,3),(10,3)).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]+RC[-1]"
```

Unlike Formula, FormulaR1C1 has relative referencing.

Comment: Your example is not in an acceptable syntax. Did you mean `Range(Cells(1,3),Cells(10,3)).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]+RC[-1]"`?

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
            Sub calc()


            Range("C1:C10").FormulaR1C1 = "=(R10C1+R10C2)"


            End Sub
```