# Adding an Offset Row to a Given Range. Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, auto-increment

I have a variable which at the beginning is set to a given range.

I want to have a loop statement that would take the next row down from the end of the given range and add it to that range.

ie:

```
myRows = Range(1:10)

    For Each cell in myRows

       If cell.Value > 2048 Then

           myRows = myRows + myRows.Offset(1, 0) ---This is where i need help---
```

Basically how do i auto increment the range each time the loop runs.

Edit:

Also how would I Add to the front of the range. As well as Take away from the back of the range.

ie

Range(1:10) is unhidden
Range(11:20) is hidden

I want to add one to the unhidden range which would take away from the hidden range so its:

Range(1:11) is unhidden
Range(12:20) is hidden

Comment: So once your criteria is met, you would basically like to concatenate the value of the current cell and the value of the cell directly below it? Do you then wish to keep the value of the cell directly below it intact and skip to the next cell? Or do you wish to delete that row?

Comment: It's a bad idea to change the range you're looping through inside the loop. I think a Do Loop is probably more appropriate, but I can't tell why you want to increase it so it's hard to say.

Comment: The reason I am changing it in the loop is because I am trying to have a spillover type thing happening. So once a cell in the range reaches a cap then it adds a new cell to the range and starts filling up that cell to its cap, and so on and so forth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `myRows` as a `Variant` data type. You need to declare it as a `Range` object.

`Dim myRows as Range`

Then you would need to use the `Set` keyword to assign a `Range` object).

`Set myRows = Range("1:10")`

Then, use the range `.Resize` method:

`Set myRows = myRows.Resize(myRows.Rows.Count+1, myRows.Columns.Count)`

Otherwise, if you need to maintain `myRows` as type Variant, let me know and I can re-work this.

Comment: Forgot to mention I do have it set as a range in the front, but the Resize looks like it is what I am looking for. Could you take a look at my Edited post at the top to see if the resize will handle the same thing?

Comment: I think it can be done with `Offset` *and* `Resize` methods, but do heed @Dick Kusleika's comment, it is generally a bad idea and might lead to some undesired results, if you change the range you're looping through, inside the loop.

Comment: The reason I am changing the range in the loop is because I am looking for some kind of spill over functionality (kind of like stack overflow) where once the cell in the range reaches its cap then a row is added and that new row starts to fill up, onto infinity.

Comment: The loop will **NOT** operate on the rows that you add to the range.

Comment: what if add to the range outside of the loop then have a GoTo command to go back to the beginning of the Loop. how would doing that fit in to spill over kind of thing that I want?

Comment: This is not a forum for an endless string of "What if..." questions. Do your coding, and when you have *specific* problems with it, post a new question.  In the meantime, if the method above answers the immediate question, please mark it as "Accepted." You'll get more help if you follow forum guidelines here.  Cheers.

Comment: Part of my question is how to simultaneously take a row from one range variable and give it to another range variable. That wasnt answered yet. I was responding you your comment with the whatif, and was clearifying why I was doing what I was doing in the comment before. I am following the guidelines. Thanks.

Comment: I will repost with my entire code and see if that clears up things.

Comment: You have what seems to be three questions now. Originally there was one question: *how do i auto increment the range each time the loop runs.*  I answered this, and gave you some suggestions for the new/follow-up questions.  Generally using a `GoTo` command like you're suggesting is probably not ideal, either (you'll need to add more logic to prevent infinite loops, new variables to identify whether/when to `GoTo`, etc.). It makes messy code. You need to look at more efficient ways to structure your code. Nobody can help you with that, unless you post your full code.

Comment: thanks. full code is up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17792339/excel-vba-spill-over-loop

Answer (score 3):

You may also use

```
Set myRows = Union(myRows, myRows.Offset(1, 0))
```

EDIT:

You asked for it!

To remove one row from generic range

```
Set myRows = RemoveRowFromRange(myRows, 10)

...

Function RemoveRowFromRange(ByVal Range As Range, row_number As Long) As Range
    With Range.Worksheet
        Select Case row_number
        Case 1
            Set Range = Intersect(Range, .Range(.Rows(2), .Rows(.Rows.Count)))
        Case .Rows.Count
            Set Range = Intersect(Range, .Range(.Rows(1), .Rows(.Rows.Count - 1)))
        Case Else
            Set Range = Union(Intersect(Range, .Range(.Rows(1), .Rows(row_number - 1))), Intersect(Range, .Range(.Rows(row_number + 1), .Rows(.Rows.Count))))
        End Select
    End With
    Set RemoveRowFromRange = Range
End Function
```

Comment: how will union work with the edit that I added to my original post?

Comment: That's not so easy. If both ranges are simple rectangles, you may use `Set Range2 = Range2.Resize(Range2.Rows.Count-1, Range2.Columns.Count).Offset(1,0)`.

Comment: the ranges have formulas in the cells within them, is this what you mean by simple rectangles or do you mean the actual cell dimensions?

Comment: Not dimensions. Shape of selected cells. You may have a composite range with, eg, 1:10,12:20,30:30: this range is composed by 3 areas (what I called "rectangles"): 1:10 and 12:20 and 30:30. To remove one line from this range, you can not just `.Resize`.

Comment: then how would I go about taking a row from a range of hidden rows and placing it within a range of unhidden rows?