# Add formula dynamically

Tags: vba

I have a loop where I create rows but I do not know how many beforehand

```
for i = 1 to dic.Keys
'Create Row
next
```

Now I want to add a formula to each row like `(B2+C2)` into the second row that I created and so on.

I know how to add a formula to a cell with `(Range.Formula="=xxx")` but cannot make this dynamic. There is a similar [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15522538/set-formula-to-a-range-of-cells) on SO but here they import the forumlas in one single step for all rows but my rows are not there yet. I could count the produced rows and apply this solution but this is not the first option for me. Anyone who could help me with this?

So I am looking for something like:

```
Range.Formula = "=B" & i "+ C" & i
```

Comment: I don't understand - whats wrong with Range.Formula = "=B" & i "+ C" & i ?

Comment: try it, it is not working. A forumla must be in double quotes like "=..." this is not the case above. but if you use double qoutes it is not possible to use variables inside.

Comment: You can't do Range.Formula = "=B" & "+C" & "1". You need to do something like Range("A" & i ).Formula = = "=B" & "+C" & "1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
for i = 1 to dic.Keys
'Create Row
'your code here...
 Range("A" & i).Formula = "=B" & i & "+ C" & i
next
```

Comment: Is this working for you? If I use exactely this code I get a compilation error. The whole formula is 'red' and "+ C" is marked as a syntax error.

Comment: Sorry - missed an & - try now