# VBA Apply Formula to All Cells not Working

Tags: vba, excel

I need to apply the formula to all cells on Sheet2 and am getting the "Method'Range' of object'_Global' failed" error.

Here's the VBA code I'm using:

```
Range("D2:AJ" & LastRow).Formula = "=OFFSET(Sheet1!$D$2,(ROW(1:1)-1)+INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/2)*8,COLUMN(A:A)-1)"
```

The formula copies every 2 rows from Sheet1 and skips 8 rows and it's working when I manually enter it.

Could you please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks much!

Comment: It works for me, what is the value of `LastRow` when it errors?

Comment: I believe the last time I saw this, it was do to the documentation I was referencing was for a different version of Excel. You might want to double check. Function naming has changed with each iteration of Excel.

Comment: The code does work for me if `LastRow` is an actual value, if it has no value, then I get the same error.

Comment: `LastRow` would be `0`. FWIW you should qualify that `Range` call with a proper `Worksheet` object instance - unqualified like this, it points to the hidden `_Global` module which essentially redirects to `ActiveSheet`, so `ActiveSheet.Range(...)` would already be an improvement.

Comment: That is strange, I do have values in the last row and am still getting error. I also changed it to "ActiveSheet.Range(...)" and it didn't work. I'll have to go with another approach here. Thanks for checking guys!

Comment: Put a breakpoint on your line and tell us what LastRow contains just before the code fails - we're all eager to hear about this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the formula into the first cell, then copying and pasting into the rest as per this answer here: [Set formula to a range of cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15522538/set-formula-to-a-range-of-cells)