# Automating a formula in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I have the below VBA script that I've created and need help with the automation of the formula.

```
Sub FuzzyMatchColumns()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim Lastrow As Long

    Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each c In Range("H2:H" & Lastrow)
         c.Formula = "=FuzzyPercent(A2,B2)"
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

At the moment it fills column H with the calculated result of `"=FuzzyPercent(A2,B2)"`

However, I need it to be dynamic - ie for `A2,B2` to increment as the VBA moves down a row.

Please note - The `FuzzyPercent(,)` formula has already been defined in a separate VBA (this functions correctly).
Apologies if this is the incorrect method of going about this.
Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Get rid of the loop: `Range("H2:H" & Lastrow).Formula = "=FuzzyPercent(A2,B2)"`.

Comment: See the linked dupe but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27825050/9245853), not the accepted one.